# Swift coredata sort by relationship property?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a Place entity which contains a list of Photo.
How I can fetch my places getting the photos ordered by date create ?
In other words how I can sort by relationship property ? Txs !

Comment: You need to sort photos for one Place object at a time so maybe it’s better to do it afterwards

Comment: Do you mean is not possible ? I have to sort mannually after my coredata req ?

Comment: Possible? Well it is not practical to do it directly in core data that is for sure, most likely not possible either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A to-many relationship is always an unordered set.

An option is to add a computed property `sortedPhotos` in `Place`. `photos` represents the relationship and is supposed to be declared as native `Set<Photo>`:

```
var sortedPhotos : [Photo] {
    return photos.sorted{ $0.creationDate < $1.creationDate }
}
```

Another option – if you want to fetch all photos of one specific place - fetch the `Photo` entity with predicate `"place.name == %@", place.name` and add a sort descriptor.

Comment: Ok txs Vadian it's what I ve done before... Crazy we cannot do that like a sql sub req...